# Subtract times in Excel in the correct data type and insert into new column with C# from imported Data from MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have written the following code and unfortunately I can't figure out why one thing is not working.

The section `// Datenzeilen verarbeiten und Differenz berechnen` is supposed to subtract the columns `StartTime` from `EndTime` in my Excel files that I have imported from SQL and insert them into the column M `NumberOfWorkingHours`. The part is a bit further down in the code in the function `SqltoExcelButton_Click`. Unfortunately I have problems with the time formats in Excel. The two times are in the form `[h]:mm:ss`. The column M `NumberOfWorkingHours` is still empty and currently has the data type `Standard`.

Does anyone know how I can make the subtraction work correctly and also insert it correctly into the column? I have the following Debug output: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'`.

Thank you in advance for your answers.
The debug output arises because of these lines:

```
                                // Datenzeilen verarbeiten und Differenz berechnen
                                for (int rowIndex = 2; rowIndex <= dataTable.Rows.Count + 1; rowIndex++)
                                {
                                    object startTimeObj = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 2]["StartTime"];
                                    object endTimeObj = dataTable.Rows[rowIndex - 2]["EndTime"];

                                    if (startTimeObj != DBNull.Value && endTimeObj != DBNull.Value)
                                    {
                                        DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTimeObj);
                                        DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endTimeObj);
                                        TimeSpan workingHours = endTime - startTime;

                                        worksheet.Cell(rowIndex, columnCount).Value = workingHours.ToString(@"\[h\]:mm:ss");
                                        if (rowIndex > 2) // Überschrift der Spalte M nicht formatieren
                                        {
                                            worksheet.Cell(rowIndex, columnCount).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "[h]:mm:ss"; // Setze das Zellenformat auf [h]:mm:ss
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        worksheet.Cell(rowIndex, columnCount).Value = "N/A"; // Setze einen Wert für ungültige Datumsangaben
                                    }
                                }
```

The times are designed in this form:
19:00:00

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Please read on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to reduce your shared code to only represent your core problem. This makes it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also please include include in which exact line the error occures.

Comment: @Felix I hope that it is now easier to see in which line the error occurs.

Comment: The error is associated to one single line of your code. It would be great if you could specify which line exatly that is.
Also, it would be helpfull if you could provide a smaple of your time data that you try to process.

Concearning the minimal example: You still have 500 lines of code posted including your complete main window code. Most of these lines are not even remotely associated to your problem. A minimal example would contain the very basics of your window, some code to load a file and processing of a single row of time values. Nothing more.

Comment: An even better minimal example would be processing of two constant `DateTime` values without any excel interference. (Given, you can reproduce the error that way.)

Comment: @Felix I hope it is correct now. Do you have any idea how I can solve my problem?